# Easier way of using TimeSeriesSplit with a constant validation set size?

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, cross-validation

The train/validation sets I require for a cv parameter in GridSearchCV should look something like this:

```
[1,2,3][4]
[1,2,3,4][5]
[1,2,3,4,5][6]
```

To solve this I rewrote the indices within the TimeSeriesSplit function:

```
tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=8)
cv_start = round(len(dataframe) * 0.98)
count = -1
for train_index, test_index in tscv.split(trainY):
    count += 1
    train_index = list(range(cv_start + count))
    test_index = list(range(cv_start + count, cv_start + count +1))
    print(train_index, test_index)
```

Is there an easier or cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose `n_splits` in such a way so that the test set contains what you want.

Similar idea is used in my other answer here:-

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/43360172/3374996

Assuming your data have 6 samples:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]()

# Here put the number you want in test data,
# I used 1 because your example has only 1 test data in each split
num_in_test = 1

test_size = float(num_in_test) / len(X)

n_splits = int((1//test_size)-1)

tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=n_splits)

for train_index, test_index in tscv.split(X):
    print(X[train_index], X[test_index])

# Output
(array([1]), array([2]))
(array([1, 2]), array([3]))
(array([1, 2, 3]), array([4]))
(array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([5]))
(array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), array([6]))
(array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]), array([7]))
```

Once your n_splits is fixed, you can easily pass your TimeSeriesSplit object to GridSearchCV or any other utility.